# Matrix index from vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

In MATLAB, I want to retrieve the value of a particular position in a matrix through a vector

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4];
A(v)
A(v(:))
```

how can I do that?

The length of the vector is not fixed so I cannot hardcode `A(v(1), v(2), v(3), v(4))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `v` to a cell-array (say `cellv`) using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and then extract elements of `cellv` as comma separated values to index `A`  and implement `A(v(1), v(2), v(3), v(4), ... v(n))` in a generalised manner.

```
cellv = num2cell(v);
A(v{:})
```